# get node value from node selected attribute

Tags: c#, xml, attributes, selectsinglenode

I have a noob problem. I select a node by its attribute and than I would like to get its children node value, but I always get the first node values instead.
My xml:

```
<Sites>
  <Site ID="032">
    <Name>
    Rome
    </Name>
    <Code>
      ---
    </Code>
    <Visible>
      true
    </Visible>
</Site>
  <Site ID="040">
    <Name>
    Paris
    </Name>
    <Code>
      ---
    </Code>
    <Visible>
      true
    </Visible>
<Site>
  <Site ID="055">
    <Name>
    Berlin
    </Name>
    <Code>
      ---
    </Code>
    <Visible>
      true
    </Visible>
</Site>
</Sites>
```

My code:

```
XmlDocument xSite = new XmlDocument();
xSite.Load("Data\\Site.xml");
XmlNode siteNode = xSite.SelectSingleNode("/Sites/Site[@ID='" + _selectedSite.ID + "']");
string sitenodestr = siteNode.InnerText;
_selectedSite.Code = siteNode.SelectSingleNode("//Code").InnerText.Trim();
_selectedSite.Name = siteNode.SelectSingleNode("//Name").InnerText.Trim();
string visib = siteNode.SelectSingleNode("//Visible").InnerText.Trim();
_selectedSite.Visibility = Convert.ToBoolean(visib);
```

I checked and the ID is correct, and also siteNode content is correct, but I always get the Name of the first Site (rome in the example).
can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be just not

```
siteNode.SelectSingleNode("//Code")...
```

but

```
siteNode.SelectSingleNode("Code")...
```

It is because `//Code` Xpath expression means "All "Code" elements in the document", but you need only children of `siteNode`.

See [Xpath syntax examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You write `siteNode.SelectSingleNode("//Code")` which target all Code nodes instead of `siteNode.SelectSingleNode("Code")` to only target the Code node inside your element.